# Using Promise.all on the entries of a Map()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I am using a Map for some key/value pairs

```
let myMap = new Map()
myMap.set('foo', 'bar')
myMap.set('foo2', 'bar42')
```

For every Map entry I execute a function which returns a Promise. All these Promises can be executed in parallel using `Promise.all`.

This is how I do it right now:

```
let mapPromises = []
myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
  mapPromises.push(MyModel.forge({key, language, value}).save())
})
await Promise.all(mapPromises)
```

***Is there another (shorter?, faster?) approach to accomplish this than pushing all function calls into an array and then triggering `Promise.all`?***

Comment: `Is there a smarter way` - smarter than what? you haven't shown how you do it

Comment: "*For every Map entry I execute a function*" - aren't you already using an iterator for that?

Comment: I rephrased the original question a bit. Thanks for pointing out its flaws.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest code I could come up with is

```
await Promise.all(Array.from(myMap, ([key, value]) => 
    MyModel.forge({key, language, value}).save())
);
```

See [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) documentation

Answer (score 6):

Yes, using `forEach` and manually pushing to an array is almost always a bad idea.

You can directly create the [array from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) the map, mapping over it in the process:

```
async function processEntry([key, value]) {
    return MyModel.forge({key, value}).save();
}

(async function() {
    let myMap = new Map()
    myMap.set('foo', 'bar')
    myMap.set('foo2', 'bar42')

    const results = await Promise.all(Array.from(myMap, processEntry));
}());
```

But if you want to use an iterator, you also can do something like

```
function* processEntries(map) {
    for (const [key, value] of map)
        yield MyModel.forge({key, value}).save();
}

(async function() {
    let myMap = new Map()
    myMap.set('foo', 'bar')
    myMap.set('foo2', 'bar42')

    const results = await Promise.all(processEntries(myMap));
}());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert a Map to an array of pairs, key first, value second. Then use `array.map` to construct your array of promises to feed to `Promise.all`.

```
var pairs = Array.from(myMap); // [['foo', 'bar'], ['foo2', 'bar42']]
```

Comment: Just use the second parameter of `from` if you plan to `map` the array

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
const myArr = [...myMap.entries()].map(([key, value]) => {
  return MyModel.forge({key, language, value}).save()
});

Promise.all(myArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the iterator on your map like this:

```
myMap[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  yield this.get("foo");
  yield this.get("foo2");
};
```

after that You can use your Map with Promise.all():

```
let result = await Promise.all(myMap);
```